# PPTK Python: Is it possible to visualise point cloud realtime?

Tags: python, camera, point-clouds, pptk

I'm making photogrametry project and I'd like to make it works realtime. If pptk cannot do this, maybe You know library that enables such action.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you run this code, when you pres "R" , point cloud will reloaded with random 1000 RGB points.

```
import time
import keyboard
import pptk
import numpy as np

while True:

    if keyboard.is_pressed("r"):
        P = np.random.rand(1000, 3)  # random RGB colors
        v.load(P,P[:,2])
        time.sleep(0.1)
```